pine script to calculate support1
I find difficulty in creating pine script code to calculate support1 and average of last 3 supports and plot as line.
average of last 3 days s1 s(d)+s(d-1)+s(d-2)/3
I would like to have pine script code for the same to create line so that I try some strategy in that. Please give an answer

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Not 100% sure what the real issue is what have you tried but I think you acn try to use this Pine Script code to calculate the Support 1 (S1) and the average of the last 3 support levels and plot them as lines:
// this is using version 4
study("Support and Average Support", overlay=true)

// Function to calculate Support 1 (S1)
s1 = low[1] - (high[1] - low[1])

// Function to calculate the average of the last 3 supports
avg_support = (s1 + s1[1] + s1[2]) / 3

plot(s1, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="Support 1")
plot(avg_support, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="Average Support")

This script calculates the Support 1 (S1) as the low of the previous candle minus the difference between the high and low of the previous candle. Then, it calculates the average of the last 3 support levels by summing up the last 3 S1 values and dividing by 3. Then we just plot both Support 1 and the average support lines on the chart.

Thanks. Exactly this is I want. Can you please elaborate the same for s2, s3 and Pivot point averages for 3 days. Plot line should be a single line, but this is reflecting as spline in charting. Would be much helpful. Thanks in advance.
